# Generic tuple type for [function,...params] with low overhead?

Tags: typescript, tuples

I'd like to tell the type checker that such and such tuples must each consist of a function and valid arguments, e.g.

```
let expressions:TYPE[] = [
    [(a:number, b:string)=>{},1,"ok"], // ok
    [(a:number)=>{},true] // error
    [(a:number)=>{}] // error
    [(a:number, b:string)=>{},1] // error
]
```

The current solution I have uses a function. It gets redundant:

```js
expression<F extends (...args:any[])=>any>(fn:F, ...params:Parameters<F>){
return [fn,...params]
}

let queue:ReturnType<expression>[] = [
    expression(...),
    expression(...),
    expression(...),// seriously?
]
```

It might be tolerable if I could do it in one call, e.g.

```js
let queue = expressions(
    [(a:number)=>{},1], // ok
    [(a:number)=>{},true] // error
    [(a:number)=>{}] // error
)
```

But writing that function is beyond me. It seems to require a generic tuple type I don't think is possible and that landed me with the `expression` function call in the first place.

Here's a naive tuple type that doesn't work / requires gross overhead.

```js
type Expression<F extends (...args:any[])=>any = (...args:any[])=>any>  = [F,...Parameters<F>]


let queue:Expression[] = [
    [(a:number)=>{},true] // No error
]

// Gross alternative:

const fn = (a:number)=>{}
queue = [
    [fn,true] as Expression<fn>  // Error as desired, but c'mon.
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem looks like this:

```
function expressions<
  F extends any[]
>(...functions: [...{
    [K in keyof F]: [
      (...arg: F[K]) => any, 
      ...F[K]
    ]
  }]
){
  return functions
}
```

We use the generic type `F` to store the the types of the arguments of the passed functions in a tuple. The type of each function  will be stored in `F[K]` which we will also use to type the second element in the tuple.

Let's see if it works:

```
let queue = expressions(
    [ (a:number, b: string) => {}, 1, "abc"],
    [ (a:boolean) => {}, true],
    [ (a: Date) => {}, new Date()],
    [ (a: number) => {}, false] // Error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'
)

let queue2 = expressions(  
    [ (a: number) => {} ] // Error: 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgKYA8AOAnVBnPRCPAHmGWQDE10ZUIATPZAQwgE8BtAXWAD4AFADoR4aPCR4AXMk4ihAb3KyA0sjgoA1qnYIQVbjM7CRLbAHMZlTiu4BKZAF4+rDgBpk867d4UAvrx2ShS4MGDYKGKwRHjAfsDAADaoMMgAjmComU40OPiEkgLKFJzIAixSEGAAtgBGqNgetTJ4MNga5g7OyAp+HgCMHgBELLVQQ9xuxbJlFbUICMlsXS69Hm2Zk9Ol5TIAIix0Kz19yBCoAO7IB3QCdlsUJbMyVXUNx2vIICyJeKiBCWSqQyWVQACYchg8gQYgIKNtnmcavVsB8-MhuPC7ICUulMpkAMyQrC4GGFeGPGa7ZAAchYNLRHhptRpGKxQA)

Comment: Ah, this looks close! I should've noted that I need to handle functions with one or more params, e.g. `[fn,1,2,3]`. Updated question to make that more clear. Really appreciate this answer though and am rolling it around!

Comment: Ok, rolled this around a bit and am not following how this works  (though it does work!)...
I'm thinking that the `K` in `[K in keyof F]` ends up being `0|1|2|3` for queue and am not sure how `K` in `(...arg: F[K])` isn't also `0|1|2|3`, or I'm not following how are why `F` becomes the arguments for the function in index 0 for that specific entry in `functions`...  Also don't think I really understand the`[...{}]` syntax for the functions typing...

Comment: Yes, the syntax used here is very uncommon so it is difficult to understand. The `[...{ ... }]` syntax allows us to "destructure" the passed array and process each element individually. This is the only way to express relations between individual "things" for each element in an array. `F` is an array of all the parameters of the functions, so `F[K]` are the parameters for the function at index `K`.

Comment: Maybe what I'm missing is _why_ "`F` is an array of all the parameters of the functions". To accomplish that I'd expect to see a `Parameters<??>`  somewhere... unless `(...arg: F[K])...` is how we're specifying that?

Comment: By specifying `(...arg: F[K])`, TypeScript will use whatever it finds there and stores it in `F[K]`. `F` is an array because the result of mapping over an array is also an array since TypeScript 3.1 (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html).